# Search string for a certain character

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form that requires a user to enter a part number, such as "XY12345E678". Then, with an `if`-statement have the program search the 7th position and do some code based on what character is in that position. In this case it will either be an "E" or "F".

For example:

```
      Dim partNumber as String
      partNumber = textboxPartNumber.Text
      Dim seventhPosition as String
      seventhPosition = partNumber.Substring(7, 1)

      If seventhPosition *is an "E"*
      ''' Do some code '''
      ElseIf seventhPosition *is an "F"*
      ''' Do some code '''
      Else
      ''' Do some code '''
```

Comment: What is it you're stuck on?  You compare with `=`

Comment: @BanksySan The conditions for the if-statement. Is it just as simple as "If seventhPosition = "E"  Then...??

Comment: Yes. Google would have said so too! [**Comparison Operators in Visual Basic**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself writing long `If...ElseIf... ElseIf...` statements then you should consider using [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) instead, like this:

```
Dim partNumber As String = textboxPartNumber.Text

If partNumber.Length >= 7 Then
    Dim seventhPosition As String = partNumber.Substring(7, 1)
    Select Case seventhPosition
        Case "E"
            ' some code
        Case "F"
            ' some code
        Case Else
            ' it is not an "E" or "F"
    End Select

Else
    ' the part number is too short
End If
```

You don't actually need to use `=` in the case clauses, but if you want to you can use `Case Is = "E"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this...

```
         Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim partNumber As String
            partNumber = textboxPartNumber.Text
            Dim seventhPosition As String
            seventhPosition = partNumber.Substring(7, 1)

            If seventhPosition = "E" Then
                MsgBox(seventhPosition)

            ElseIf seventhPosition = "F" Then
                MsgBox(seventhPosition)
            Else
                MsgBox("others")
            End If 
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Dim partNumber As String
            partNumber = textboxPartNumber.Text

            Dim seventhPosition As String
            seventhPosition = partNumber.Chars(7)

            If seventhPosition = "E" OrElse seventhPosition = "F" Then
                'Do something
            End If
```